# Symfony2 doctrine:schema:update extremely slow

Tags: oracle, performance, symfony, doctrine, schema

So at my job, I'm working on a Symfony2 project as a software dev. We're having performance issues with the schema:update, it takes something like 10 minutes for the --dump-sql and 1 hour (yes, 1 hour, you read correctly) for the --force to complete.
Our dev environment is probably not the best, but still. 
The code is on my computer, on Win7 64 (with PHP 5.6 / apache 2.4 locally obviously)
The database is remote, in a Datacenter somewhere else, it's Oracle 12c
I've looked everywhere on the web and every person having "slow" schema:update issue is talking about something like 30 seconds, so, not even close ^^

Does anyone ever encounter such insane delay ?

Thank you again, I will be happy to provide any information.

Cheers !

Comment: Try debugging your connection to the database. It might be so that the connection itself is slow. Could you please tell us your exact symfony and doctrine versions (located in `composer.json`) as well as the size of the database?

Comment: By the way, you should really consider using [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) for your production server or you might end loosing data by using `doctrine:schema:update --force`.

Comment: Do you use `doctrine:schema:update --force` in production ??

Comment: Thank you for your time :) No this is not the production env, it's our dev database ^^ Here are the informations you asked for : num rows = 86537, 
db size = 40 Mo, 
doctrine version = 2.4.8, 
symfony version = 2.7.7

Comment: Answer updated... that should speed up a little, but I think the bottleneck is the connection to the datacenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as tftd said, it's the connexion. They migrated some stuff, now we're at 15 minutes tops. It's still a lot, but at least it's better.

Answer (score 1):

When developing it's always better to start with a fresh database and fixtures, so delete and re-create your database:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop
php app/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --env=dev
php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=dev
```

**[Edit 2020/03]**

I am now using a Makefile for all these development tasks:

```
load-fixtures: ## Build the db, control the schema validity, load fixtures and check the migration status
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:schema:drop --force
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:schema:create
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:schema:validate
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:fixtures:load -n
    $(SYMFONY) doctrine:schema:validate
```

You can find [the full version for Symfony 5 here](https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/snippets/the-perfect-makefile-for-symfony).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this DB connection, I've already spoken with the guy managing the servers. I will update this thread as soon as we find something :)